# Facebook for Android icons layout

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to mimic the layout of the icons in Facebook android app.

[image]

As you can see, this is a 2x3 layout, but if you flip it it becomes 3x2 layout. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved here: [How to setup a main menu layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535958/how-to-setup-a-main-menu-layout-in-android/3536387#3536387)

You can supply two layout files for landscape and portrait specifying the number of columns in the gridview in each case to achieve the 2X3 vs 3x2

```
TextView tv;
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "font.ttf");
                tv.setTypeface(tf);
                tv.setTextSize(10);
```

Comment: This looks great but how to add text under images? Or is text part of image?

Comment: You can supply a custom layout to the GridView adapter. You can set the font, typeface, size, style, etc for the TextView